# Compressing PDF with Java library

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pdfbox, image-compression

Im building a chat platform and Im implementing upload-attachments.
For that I need to use a couple of libraries to compress the files (pdf, image, video).
Im using lambda to do this.
Image compression is working fine.
Video compression Im working on it right now, to compress (mp4, avi, x264).
The difficult part is the PDF.
In the PDF there is a case that it contains images inside, or something else... To use this library, Im using this

```
`        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>`
```

And the code for the compression is this

```
public class PdfCompressor implements MediaCompressor {

    public byte[] compress(MediaData media) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = media.getData();
        if (data == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data must not be null");
        }

        try (PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
             ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                PDResources resources = page.getResources();
                if (resources == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
                    PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
                    if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                        compressImage((PDImageXObject) xObject, document, outputStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        }
    }
  private void compressImage(PDImageXObject imageObject, PDDocument document, ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        // Only compress supported image formats
        String format = imageObject.getSuffix();
        if (format == null || !(format.equals("jpg") || format.equals("jpeg") || format.equals("png") || format.equals("bmp"))) {
            outputStream.write(imageObject.getStream().toByteArray());
            return;
        }

        // Compress the image
        BufferedImage image = imageObject.getImage();
        ByteArrayOutputStream compressedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PDImageXObject compressedImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, image);
        ImageIO.write(compressedImage.getImage(), format, compressedStream);
        byte[] compressedImageData = compressedStream.toByteArray();

        // Check if compressed size is less than original size
        if (compressedImageData.length < imageObject.getStream().getLength()) {
            outputStream.write(compressedImageData);
        } else {
            outputStream.write(imageObject.getStream().toByteArray());
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the code is increasing the size of the PDF, and not only that, it is also damaging the file, which means that I cant open it after that.

Lambda, trying to upload it to S3 bucket.

Comment: Well, it's not really surprising that your code *damages the file* - reading your code one sees that you return concatenated bitmaps, not a PDF at all.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it, but now Im getting an empty PDF, which means that the code removed all the text...
I checked also with PDF that contains images, and instead of reducing the size, its increased it...

Comment: Ideally PDFs are already nicely compressed. Some PDFs aren't, but there can be many reasons for that. I wouldn't waste my time for this.

Comment: *"You are right, I fixed it, but now Im getting an empty PDF, which means that the code removed all the text... "* - Most likely that means that your code still has some bugs as pdfbox does not remove text unless your code makes it do so.